# How do I build Nim library packages

Tags: nim-lang

I've created a nimble **library** package as per the [documentation](https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble#creating-packages). When I try to build it using `nimble build` I get the following error.

> Error: Nothing to build. Did you specify a module to build using the `bin` key in your .nimble file?

I can do this and it does fix the error but according to the documentation adding the `bin` key to the `.nimble` file turns my package into a **binary** package.

Other things I have tried:

- **Use `nimble install`:** This does not appear to verify that my code will actually compile and will happily install anything to the local package directory (I added a C# class to my `.nim` file, for example, and it was successfully installed).
- **Use `nimble c`:** This works but I have to pass in the path to the `nim` file I want to compile and the `binDir` entry in the `.nimble` file is ignored resulting in the output being placed in the same directory as the file being built. This complicates the development cycle because I have to manually clean up after the compiler.
- **Use the compiler directly**. This is pretty much the same as the previous option with the same flaws.

I guess I could also create a separate `.nim` file and import my library after it is installed but this is a big overhead for just wanting to verify that a package in the early stages of development will actually compile.

I just want to be able to verify that the source code in my library package is syntactically correct and will compile. How is this meant to be done for **library** packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your provided link to the nimble package manager documentation I have the feeling that

https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble#tests

is what you are looking for. But I have never used the test command, so I am not sure. I do my test manually still, I read the nimble docs maybe 4 years ago and can not really remember. And currently there is much package manager related work going on, I heard there is a new, alternative package manager called nimph, and from a forum thread I think I read something that nimble is going to change and improve also. Maybe you should consider subscribing to the Nim forum, that is the place where the bright Nim devs are. Well, at least a few of them.

Comment: It's obvious now that you have pointed it out but I totally overlooked nimble test because my package didn't have any tests in it yet. Obviously the tests depend on the code so they will be built when the test suite is run. Thanks